# Plot histogram on non distirbuted data

Tags: pandas, histogram

I have a pandas series like

```
0      22.0
1      38.0
2      26.0
3      35.0
4      35.0
5       NaN
6      54.0
7       2.0
8      27.0
9      14.0
10      4.0
11     58.0
12     20.0
13     39.0
14     14.0
15     55.0
16      2.0
17      NaN
```

while trying to plot on a an histogram like

```
plt.hist(train_df['Age'])
```

I have the following error:

```
ValueError: max must be larger than min in range parameter
```

Comment: You could just do: `train_df.Age.plot(kind='hist'); plt.show()`

Comment: Looks like that syntax has trouble with NaNs -- seems like a bug probably.  The message is confusing b/c it's sort of trying to say something like 58.0 is not > NaN.  Computer code is kind of dumb like that.  ;-)   You can do as coldspeed does or alternatively you could remove the NaNs with `plt.hist(df['age'][df.age.notnull()])`